# Multiple attributions per line in Python versus C

Tags: python, c, translation

Doing my best at understanding how python works. I come from a somewhat solid C background.

Trying to translate the following line into C:
    `p, q = q, p - x // y * q`

My problem is that multiple assertions/attributions (please correct me on terminology) don't work as I expect them to.

How does that line of code actually unwrap into C-like syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any [assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) works by first evaluating the expression on the right side, then assigning it to the target list.<sup>1</sup>

---

In your case, the right side is a [tuple display](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tut-tuples) with two elements:

```
q, p - x // y * q
```

So, Python evaluates the first element, `q`, then it evaluates the second element, `p - x // y * q`, then it builds a tuple out of those two values.

Next, since you have a target list with two targets on the left side, Python uses iterable unpacking (described in the same Tuples and Sequences tutorial section)<sup>2</sup> to unpack that tuple into two separate values, and assign one to each target.

So, in C terms, it's roughly:

```
_tmp1 = q
_tmp2 = p - x // y * q
_tmp3 = (_tmp1, _tmp2)
p = _tmp3[0]
q = _tmp3[1]
```

In fact, a real Python implementation might optimize out that build-a-tuple/unpack-a-tuple code, the same way you would if writing this yourself, so what you get is more like:

```
_tmp = p - x // y * q
p = q
q = _tmp
```

---

If you're used to C, you might be used to looking at the assembly that a compiler generates (without optimizations disabled) to figure out what something really means. You can do the same thing in Python with the [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) module, except that the assembly language is for CPython bytecode rather than x86_64 or ARM9 or whatever:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('p, q = q, p - x // y * q')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (q)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (p)
              4 LOAD_NAME                2 (x)
              6 LOAD_NAME                3 (y)
              8 BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE
             10 LOAD_NAME                0 (q)
             12 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             14 BINARY_SUBTRACT
             16 ROT_TWO
             18 STORE_NAME               1 (p)
             20 STORE_NAME               0 (q)
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE
```

And as you can see, in CPython 3.7, it actually *did* optimize out the tuple, and also optimized out the temporary local variables and just stored intermediate values anonymously on the stack.

---

<sub>1. This is slightly oversimplified, because a target like `spam[eggs][0] = …` actually requires evaluating `spam[eggs]` as an expression, and then treating `<the result of that>[0]` as a target… but that isn't relevant here.</sub>

<sub>2. The tutorial calls this "sequence unpacking", because it hasn't gotten to the notion of "iterable" yet.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You'd do the equivalent thing in C with:

```c
temp = p - x / y * q; 
p = q; 
q = temp;
```

But what's *really* going on is that the right hand side creates a tuple, with the tuple items being built left to right:

```py
t = (q, p - x // y * q)
```

And then that tuple gets unpacked on the left hand side:

```
p = t[0]
q = t[1]
```

This use of tuples for essentially parallel assignment comes in *very* handy. And I'm sure you'll get used to it very quickly.

But one thing that may take a little longer to get used to is Python's data model, which works rather differently to C's. You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.